# Setting the image of a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, deprecated

I usually change the images of my buttons using this:`[Button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`And I just noticed today that this code is deprecated. What would be the correct syntax for changing a button's image?

Comment: What makes you think this method is deprecated?

Comment: Can you provide some more info regarding your question?????i mean,what you have tried???

Comment: See below for the Quick Help message I get with this code since Xcode's latest update. Replacing the code by `[[Button imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]]`seems to solve this, but the app still needs to know what the control state is to display the image on the button.

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct syntax, (assuming you have a `UIButton` instance called `Button`). That method has not been deprecated.

Comment: Here is what I see in the Quick Help Section:
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image
Description The image to use as content for the cell.
Availability iOS (2.0 and later) Deprecated: Instead use the imageView property to get UIImageView object and then get or set the encapsulated image.
Declared UITableViewCell.h
Reference UITableViewCell Class Reference
Guides 
Table View Programming Guide for iOS

Comment: That is why you can't use the `setImage:` method, but in your example, you are using `setImage:forState:` which is not deprecated. And as the documentation says, you could instead use: `[[Button imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]]`.

Comment: This code alone doesn't seem to work. I think the app needs to know what the control state is (but it does solve the problem of the Quick Help message)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. You won't believe the time it took me to find the solution… 
Actually, my code is like this:

`//Changes the icon image`

`[Button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

When I place the cursor after the word image, I get a Quick Help Deprecated Code message. So, I tried to find ways to correct this for a time, then I thought it could be a bug. So at first, I simply added a line break after the first line, and placed the cursor on the second line. No Deprecated Code message. Then, I simply deleted the word image.

`//Changes the icon`

`[Button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

No Deprecated Code Message…

To isolate this, I tried to keep only the word image:

`//image`

`[Button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Deprecated Code message.

Even better: Delete everything and keep only:
`//image`

Deprecated Code message. It looks a lot like a bug…